# Count in Crystal Reports C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a field that is either YES or NO and I want to display at the end of my report a count of how many "YES"s there were in that field.  I made a running total field and set the formula equal to that field ("YES"), but that shows up for every record.  I just want one number at the end.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Make a static field (int counter).  Every time you select a "Yes" just increment counter by 1.
You can access the counter to check the number of "YES".